# How to define geometry object using a different CRS code

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I need to collect multispectral imagery over a selection of regions and time. These regions are defined as rectangles, using coordinates defined in EPGS:25832. I have tried using `ee.Projection()` function, but I must be using it incorrectly as it prevents me from loading the image collection in the first place. When attempting to read the collection, I get the following error:

> ee.ee_exception.EEException: GeometryConstructors.Rectangle: Even/odd
> interiors currently only supported for geodesic cylindrical
> projections.

Here is my full code:

```
import ee
import os

ee.Initialize()
proj=ee.Projection('EPSG:25832')
bbox = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([440000, 6150000, 450000, 6160000],proj)

col=ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')\
    .filterBounds(bbox)\
    .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')\
    .select(['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B9','B11','B12'])\
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just turn off even/odd interiors:

```
bbox = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([440000, 6150000, 450000, 6160000], proj, True, False)
```

There are different ways to treat geometries with more than one closed polygon (polygons with holes). See: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule).

Earth Engine has to be able to reproject polygons from other projections in order to use them; it can only do that using geodesic cylindrical projections for polygons that have holes in them using the even/odd rule. Even though this polygon doesn't have multiple closed polygons, the reprojection code doesn't know that, so you need to tell it that you don't care about interior polygons (holes) by turning off Even/Odd interiors.

Comment: Thank you, Noel. This solved it. Can you please elaborate on why it has to be done this way? Why does this work?

Comment: There are different ways to treat geometries with more than one closed polygon (polygons with holes).   See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule.

Earth Engine has to be able to reproject polygons from other projections in order to use them; it can only do that using geodesic cylindrical projections for polygons that have holes in them using the even/odd rule.  Even those this polygon doesn't have multiple closed polygons, the reprojection code doesn't know that, so you need to tell it that you don't care about interior polygons (holes) by turning off Even/Odd interiors.