# Create a geometry object using projected coordinates?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to create a polygon using projected coordinates. I'm doing this because the raster I am using is in a projected coordinate system and using projected coordinates allows me to create a polygon that is 1000 x 1000 m. The idea here is to create a polygon that clips the raster. When trying to create the geometry object I get this error:

GeometryConstructors.Polygon: Even/odd interiors currently only supported for geodesic cylindrical projections.

I'm not 100% certain what this means. I'm assuming that I am not allowed to use the projected coordinate system I have written in my code. Is there a way I can create this object with projected coordinates?

```
var image = ee.Image("users/adrianom/california_c2014_tree_list");
// x min y min x max y max
var xmin = -421620.594734765;
var ymin = -599235.79083614;
var xmax = -420620.594734765;
var ymax = -598235.79083614;

var bl = ee.Geometry.Point([xmin, ymin]);
var br = ee.Geometry.Point([xmax, ymin]);
var tl = ee.Geometry.Point([xmin, ymax]);
var tr = ee.Geometry.Point([xmax, ymax]);

var bbox_coords = ee.List([bl, br, tl, tr])
var cali_albers = ee.Projection('EPSG:3310')
var bbox_geom = ee.Geometry.Polygon(bbox_coords, cali_albers);
print(bbox_geom)
```

Comment: Solves the main problem, thank you! There was an additional issue I fixed myself. Supplied that info in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set `evenOdd` to false and either create an enclosed polygon, with coords in the correct order or create a rectangle:

```
var xmin = -421620.594734765;
var ymin = -599235.79083614;
var xmax = -420620.594734765;
var ymax = -598235.79083614;

var bl = ee.Geometry.Point([xmin, ymin]);
var br = ee.Geometry.Point([xmax, ymin]);
var tl = ee.Geometry.Point([xmin, ymax]);
var tr = ee.Geometry.Point([xmax, ymax]);

var cali_albers = ee.Projection('EPSG:3310')

var bbox_coords = ee.List([bl, br, tr, tl, bl])
var bbox_geom = ee.Geometry.Polygon({"coords": bbox_coords, "proj": cali_albers, "evenOdd": false});
print(bbox_geom)

// OR...

var bbox_coords = ee.List([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])
var bbox_geom = ee.Geometry.Rectangle({"coords": bbox_coords, "proj": cali_albers, "evenOdd": false});
print(bbox_geom)
```

[ee.Geometry.Polygon(coords, proj, geodesic, maxError, evenOdd)](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-geometry-polygon)

> **evenOdd Boolean, optional**
>
> If true, polygon interiors will be
> determined by the even/odd rule, where a point is inside if it crosses
> an odd number of edges to reach a point at infinity. Otherwise
> polygons use the left- inside rule, where interiors are on the left
> side of the shell's edges when walking the vertices in the given
> order. If unspecified, defaults to true.

From the [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/407755/2856) by Noel Gorelick on the duplicate question:

> There are different ways to treat geometries with more than one closed
> polygon (polygons with holes). See:
> en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule. Earth Engine has to be
> able to reproject polygons from other projections in order to use
> them; it can only do that using geodesic cylindrical projections for
> polygons that have holes in them using the even/odd rule. Even though
> this polygon doesn't have multiple closed polygons, the reprojection
> code doesn't know that, so you need to tell it that you don't care
> about interior polygons (holes) by turning off Even/Odd interiors.

Answer (score 0):

The supplied answers solves half my problems. Setting `evenOdd` to false solves the problem of creating the object, but I am unable to map out the polygon in the map layer. If you are using bounding box coordinates, change the object type to `ee.Geometry.Rectangle`. This allowed me to map out the object.